# CSS Добавить ::after к любому элементу после указанного?

Tags: html, css, css3

Подскажите, пожалуйста как добавить псевдокласс любому следующему элементу ? Хочу что-то по типу

```css
h1:empty+* {
  position: relative;
}

h1:empty+* ::after {
  content: 'You forgot text for h1';
}
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<div></div>
<p>text</p>
```

Comment: Если убрать пробел после звездочки в ```h1:empty+* ::after```, это то, что вы хотите?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
h1:empty + * {
  position: relative;
}

h1:empty + *::after {
  content: 'You forgot text for h1';
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<div></div>
<p>text</p>
```